# How do I install ansible-galaxy on mac os using brew?

Tags: ansible, homebrew, ansible-galaxy

Is it possible to install ansible galaxy using brew on mac os? I tried:

```
$ brew install ansible-galaxy
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 3 taps (homebrew/cask-versions, homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Formulae
git-lfs ✔                cpprestsdk               exercism                 gobject-introspection    kube-aws                 minio-mc                 remarshal                teleport                 vegeta
ammonite-repl            ddgr                     fluent-bit               grpc                     libimagequant            nailgun                  root                     terraform_landscape      xsimd
angular-cli              dscanner                 fmt                      instead                  librealsense             node-build               serverless               tinyxml2                 you-get
arx                      duo_unix                 fruit                    ios-deploy               libsass                  opencv@2                 sfcgal                   tty-solitaire
conan                    elektra                  git-quick-stats          jdupes                   libvirt                  osrm-backend             snappystream             urdfdom_headers
console_bridge           ethereum                 gitbucket                kallisto                 minio                    parallelstl              sysdig                   vagrant-completion

Error: No available formula with the name "ansible-galaxy"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: `ansible galaxy` is a subcommand of `ansible`, so install `ansible` and you'll get `ansible galaxy`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once you install ansible on your machine using **brew** or **pip** you will get **ansible-galaxy** automatically it's not a package it's a subcommand of the ansible like **ansible-vault** **ansible-doc** etc.

[image]